# wordpress: how to add a custom static HTML page template?

Tags: html, wordpress

is it possible with the dashboard to add custom static HTML files for generating new webpages ?

if not what's the easiest way ?

and how to make sure this pages are categorizable and also referencable on google search engine?

Comment: The content of a wordpress page can be defined in a template. You can create a template with static HTML with the relevent wordpress short tags in it. Look at the editor for examples of exisiting templates.

Comment: @monkeymatrix : thanx! which editor ? could u gimme a link or a procedure?

Comment: In the Wordpress dashboard, go to Appearance->Editor. You will see a list of all the theme's files including the templates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Your theme directory You ca put some files, and name them like:

page-homepage.php

page-contact.php etc

Now, each of those files needs to open with:

```
<?php
/*
 * Template Name: Contact Page
 */
?>
```

and this header needs to de diffrent for each file (it gves the termplate a name)

Now put any html You like inside (also consider adding get_header() and get_footer(), so You have all necesary scripts and mockup.

After creating those files, when editing a page in WP You can select the file as template.

Comment: :thanx ! i have put this new php file in wp-content/theme....i am now in the dashboard/pages/add new....how to select this file as template?

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates was also useful